# php / mysql - Issue when redirecting based on user_level

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently building a control panel based on user_level. If a user has level (0) they can't access anything besides the index page, level (1) can access everything.

My problem is, with the current code I am using... It only redirects me back to the index page, even if I set my user_level above 0.

Code:

```
<?php
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
require_once("config/db.php");

$page_rows = results_per_page;

if (!$db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
    $db_connection->errors[] = $db_connection->error;
}

if($_SESSION["user_level"] == 0)
                {
                header('Location: index.php');
                }
?>
```

and If I try using the following code....

```
<?php
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
require_once("config/db.php");

$page_rows = results_per_page;

if (!$db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
    $db_connection->errors[] = $db_connection->error;
}

if($_SESSION["user_level"] == 0) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: download.php');
?>
```

I get **HTTP ERROR 500** on the download.php page.

All help is appreciated. (Sorry for any 'Noob' mistakes, This is my first bigger project).

Comment: use `session_start();` at first line, and `exit;` after header.

Comment: do print_r($_SESSION) to see what is value in session. You are checking session but not explaining how does the session value is set.

Comment: still keeps doing it :/

Comment: 500 is a server error. Either check your logs and/or place the following just underneath your opening `<?php` tag: `ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` - Also use `mysqli_error($db_connection)` for the query (whatever that may be). The `results_per_page` is *potentially* missing a `$` sign for it, since it is treated as a constant. If it wasn't defined as a constant, then that should read as `$results_per_page`. @Jixy

Answer (score 0):

You are using `session` like:

```
if($_SESSION["user_level"] == 0)
{
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

but session is not started here. Start the session on first line like:

```
session_start();
```

only after that you can access the session variable.

Comment: I tried adding "session_start();" on the first line, but it still gives the same issue.