# php / mysql - Redirect based on user_level doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

*Just wanna put this at the top, I've tried using "session_start(); at the top, and it still gives me the same issues.*

I'm currently building a control panel based on user_level. If a user has level (0) they can't access anything besides the index page, level (1) can access everything.

My problem is, with the current code I am using... It only redirects me back to the index page, even if I set my user_level above 0.

Code:

```
<?php
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
require_once("config/db.php");

$page_rows = results_per_page;

if (!$db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
    $db_connection->errors[] = $db_connection->error;
}

if($_SESSION["user_level"] == 0)
                {
                header('Location: index.php');
                }
?>
```

and If I try using the following code....

```
<?php
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
require_once("config/db.php");

$page_rows = results_per_page;

if (!$db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
    $db_connection->errors[] = $db_connection->error;
}

if($_SESSION["user_level"] == 0) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        header('Location: download.php');
?>
```

I get **HTTP ERROR 500** on the download.php page.

All help is appreciated. (Sorry for any 'Noob' mistakes, This is my first bigger project).

Comment: You're missing a close brace at the end of the second file.

Comment: `$page_rows = results_per_page;` is potentially missing a `$` sign. `results_per_page` is treated as a constant. There isn't enough code to support the question.

Comment: Note you can run `php -l <file>` to scan for obvious syntax errors. This is usually the cause of 500 errors.

Comment: You already posted this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406012/php-mysql-issue-when-redirecting-based-on-user-level please don't repost.

Comment: 500 is a server error. Either check your logs and/or place the following just underneath your opening `<?php` tag: `ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` - Also use `mysqli_error($db_connection)` for the query (whatever that may be). The `results_per_page` is *potentially* missing a `$` sign for it, since it is treated as a constant. If it wasn't defined as a constant, then that should read as `$results_per_page`.